# 2 Questions about the Opposite category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

**1.** If you have a category $\frak{A}$ how are the morphisms of its opposite category $\frak{A}^{op}$ defined?

**2.** How would you also show that $(\frak{A}^{op})^{op}=\frak{A}$?

Thanks!

Comment: That definition is specified in the definition of an opposite category: $\text{Hom}_{A^{op}}(c, d) = \text{Hom}_A(d, c)$. You can think of categories as directed graphs with extra structure (that extra structure being composition), and taking opposite categories is a construction defined on the level of directed graphs: reverse the direction of all arrows.

Comment: OK so are two Hom sets strictly equal? Or are they just bijective?

Comment: If thinking in terms of equality causes you to check whether some weird set-theoretic stuff happens, then they're in bijection in a way that respects composition; otherwise, they're equal.

Comment: (You should generally only be thinking about categories up to equivalence anyway.)

Comment: I've only started learning about this stuff so my questions are really basic. I still don't get why a morphism $f:c\rightarrow d$ in $A^{op}$ is a morphism $d\rightarrow c$ in $A$ and vice versa. Thanks

Comment: Do you know what the definition of the opposite category is?

Comment: @Jim I know it has the same objects as $A$ but I'm still not sure what morphisms it has. Are they the same as those of $A$ or are they in bijective correspondence with those of $A$?

Comment: They are the same.  As Qiaochu says we define $\text{Hom}_{A^{op}}(c, d)$ to be equal to the set $\text{Hom}_A(d, c)$.

Comment: I see it now- thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a category.

[image: category]

Here is its opposite category.

[image: categoryop]

Simple as that. Even though you might want to consider, say, the category of groups, in which a morphism $G\to H$ is actually a *function on the underlying sets* (satisfying some rules), it is still often very useful to consider categories in which morphisms don't have such concrete interpretations.

Excuse my terrible Paint skills.

Comment: $+1$ for drawing a picture.

Comment: A picture is worth thousand words !